# Access recordset not updating table

Tags: vba, ms-access-2013, recordset

I am learning how to handle Access VBA recordsets.

In the example below, I am using a SQL query to open my recorset and sort the data using `strName` col. I can see that the query is working when I am debbuging the code, however I don't know why the table is not getting updated with sorted rows. Any suggestion?

[image]

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Sub OrderDB()

    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
    Dim mySortedRS As DAO.Recordset

    'Set the DAO database to current Access db
     Set db = CurrentDb

    'Open the table as the recordset
     Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM Table1 order by strName", dbOpenDynaset)
     
    'Process the rows
    Do
    
      Debug.Print rs!strName
      rs.Edit
      rs.Update
      rs.MoveNext
      
    Loop Until rs.EOF
      
    'Cleanup
    rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
   
End Sub
```

Comment: You expect the content of your table get 'statically' sorted after your code processed it? That's definitely not the fact. The records will be sorted by your primary key (if you have one). You cant change that in any way.

Comment: Only `rs` will contain sorted records. The table remains as is.

Comment: Thanks  @UnhandledException ! I didn't know about that before. All clear now!